# React Native not compile in release

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-camera

I compile my proeject with react-native-camera and another libs to android.

when I try to compile my project in release with this code:

```
compile (project(':react-native-camera')) { 
  exclude group: "com.google.android.gms" 
  exclude group: "com.android.support"  
}
```

and I receive this error:

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   com/facebook/infer/annotation/Assertions.class

so I try to compile add infe-anotation to not compile

```
compile (project(':react-native-camera')) {
  exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
  exclude group: "com.android.support"
  exclude group: "com.facebook.infer.annotation"  
}
```

compile to release but not run the app.

Comment: Have you seen  https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/issues/1565  . Its the same bug.

Comment: I change the internal dependency to `compile 'com.facebook.infer.annotation:infer-annotation:+'`, so this fix does not have effect in my case.

Comment: Can you check if there are any duplications in your `MainApplication.java` file